How do I load a Soundfont (.sf2) and play instruments from it in a browser?
How do I load a custom Soundfont (.sf2) and play instruments from it in the browser? I am working on a web app where users can edit music via a MIDI sequencer, and put in their own soundfonts.
I see many solutions for playing MIDI events in general (such as soundfont-player. I also have seen smplr, which can load pre-rendered soundfonts and also supposedly, SF2 files for running javascript in the web, (though I tried everything to get the example to work, no luck!)
Any leads would be super helpful, thank you.

I tried everything - except, it seems, to actually write some code

Looks like the smplr works with SF2 files - not very well, but it is experimental

Haha yea it would seem that way, but i cant really write anything if i cant even get the example to work

are you saying the demo of samplr doesn't work for you?

Yes, that is what i am saying (The example snippet from the api at the bottom where it says to load the sf2)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@hidude562 - works fine
